# Block all traffic out except one port with pfctl for macOS

Tags: osx, firewall, pf

As stated in the question, I need to block all traffic out to internet except for one port on MAC OS X 10.8.x.

I just need the commands to run from a shell or edit any conf file?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your external interface is `en0` you can try the following command (allow https/443 port in this example) :

`printf "block all\npass on en0 proto { tcp,udp } from any to any port 443\n"|sudo /sbin/pfctl -Ef -`